# How to edit cell Values

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm new to the google spreadsheets API node module. I'm asking on how to edit the cell value of a sheet. I have tries following other internet videos to do it but none of them work. I have a variable called doc that is the spreadsheet and the sheet itself is called SheettoUse.

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('CODE');
            await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
              client_email: creds.client_email,
              private_key: creds.private_key,
            });
          
            await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
          
            const TicketASheet = doc.sheetsByTitle['Ticket-A']; // or use doc.sheetsById[id]

let sheet = TicketASheet
            await sheet.loadCells('A1:AAA1000');
            let cells = sheet.getCell(0,0)
            console.log(cells.value)
```

Thanks,
William

Comment: Share your work-in-progress code.

Comment: I edited the main message to show what i have done!

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but none of them work`?

Comment: So I have found tutorials of how to write to cells, but every single time it will say something like .setValue() is not a function,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.setValue() is used to update cell value in [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

**To set cell value in npmjs, You can refer to the following sample code:**

```
// update cell value
cells.value = 123.456;

// update cell formula
cells.formula = '=A1';

// update cell format
cells.textFormat = { bold: true };

// update cell note
cells.note = 'This is a note!';

await sheet.saveUpdatedCells(); // saves changes in the cell
```

**Reference:**

- [google-spreadsheet](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/)
- [GoogleSpreadsheetCell](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/classes/google-spreadsheet-cell)